# subscan-essentials EVM plugin

Tags: frontier

I've tested [subscan-essentials](https://github.com/subscan-explorer/subscan-essentials) and love how nicely a substrate-based chain gets indexed in a database. But I see that it doesn't parse [Frontier](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/) evm extrinsics. I couldn't find open-source plugins for this, maybe one of you know more than my google searches ?

Note: I know a blockscout etc (going through the eth RPC), works great too, but I was thinking about preferably using subscan-essentials.